# 2 save to update my alias with friendly ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, friendly-id

I'm using the gem Friendly ID, and I currently have to do 2 saves in order to save the slug.

It doesn't seems right to me.

```
class Contractor < ActiveRecord::Base
  include FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged, slug_column: :alias
  after_commit :generate_new_alias, unless: Proc.new {|contractor| contractor.business_name_changed? }


  def slug_candidates
      [
        :business_name,
        [:business_name, :city],
        [:business_name, :city, :state]
      ]
  end

  def generate_new_alias
    if self.alias != self.alias_was
      self.alias = nil
      self.save
    end
  end

end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: why would you do that? is that recommended by friendly id? looks like a bad practice.

Comment: I don't really understand why you are using the generate_new_alias method. I would ditch that method and remove slug_column: :alias and the after_commit call.

Comment: @rails4guides.com If I remove the `slug_column: :alias` then friendly_id has no idea which column to check for slugs.
And if i remove the after commit it never re-generate the alias.

Comment: Well, I've used it without having to specify an alias. Did you follow these instructions: https://github.com/norman/friendly_id ?

Comment: @rails4guides.com well, we use a levacy database so, I have no choice but to specify wich column to use. Also the instructions says `Slugs are no longer regenerated when a record is saved. If you want to regenerate a slug, you must explicitly set the slug column to nil` but if I do so on a before_commit I have a mysql error because alias cannot be null.

Comment: Perhaps it's not possible for your use case. Personally, what you are doing with alias seems a bit fuzzy to me.

Comment: Alias is a slug column from our legacy database.

Comment: Just a small change for the sake of readability. `self.alias != self.alias_was` is the same as `self.alias_changed?`